# X-Rite i1Display Pro - Gives my MacBook Pro a greenish tint - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: color-correction, color, monitors

I ordered an X-Rite i1Display Pro and was excited to see the corrections of colours of my old MacBook Pro (mid-2014). Well... I got somehow disappointed and now I cannot really trust i1Display Pro, nor do I know how the real colour profile should look like.

Below this text, you'll find the settings that I went through and I'm going to append a video where I see a meaningful green shift and how everything looks slightly uncontrasty.

## i1Profiler

The first thing that shocked me is that I paid "quite" much for a small dongle but the software's resolution looks way off. Just to say it simply, it looks blurry, as if it's not made for the retina display.

Have a look:

[Screenshot-2020-10-16-at-20-36-12.png](https://postimg.cc/bZbbfQnW)

If you look at the letters you see that it's blurry besides the open window of Chrome. I tested the application with a new MacBook Pro 2019 and it's the same issue. I'm just not sure why I don't see it anywhere else. Do you have the same "problem"?

## i1Profiler Settings

I try to make it short:

User Mode: Advanced -> Profiling

Display: White LED
White Point: D65
Luminance: 100 cd/m^3
Gamma: Standard with 2.2
Contrast Ratio: Native
Flare Correct and Ambient Light Smart Control: Off
Default Profile Settings: Use Default
Patch Set Size: Large
Adjust Brightness: Manual

That's about it.
Since I'm not able to afford an extra room just for colour correcting/grading, I did the measurements in a room with daylight but with no light coming directly to the monitor. Obviously, I have checked that the device lies flat.

## DisplayCal Settings

Because of i1Profiler I was disappointed, so I looked up for an alternative software and I found DisplayCal. I used it just by setting everything on auto and as measured and I actually liked the colour profile way more. The greenish tint was gone.

## Video

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to present you my changes, besides showing you a handheld video. Because I have noticed, that you are not able to see the changes on screenshots. Even screen recording doesn't show the changes that much.

So I thought to my self, that I'm using my LED light and set it to 6500 kelvin and I shot the video als0 in 6500 custom white balance.

Here is the video:

Color LCD: is the standard color profile given by apple
MacbookPro_LCD_16-10-2020.icc: Is the one made by X-Rite iProfiler
MacbookPro11, etc: Is made by DisplayCal

For both software, I have used the X-Rite i1Display Pro (just to make it clear).

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Those low-cost (sub-$1000) colorimeters are not much better than nothing at all.  The ones that work are so expensive, that it's better to rent them, and best to pay a technician to calibrate.  This is part of the appeal of FSI; you can ship the monitor back to them, and they'll re-calibrate it for free (once a year, if I remember correctly).  Here's a good article on it. https://mixinglight.com/color-grading-tutorials/dramatically-improve-low-cost-colorimeter-results-calman/

Comment: Also, having a "greenish" tint doesn't mean anything, and isn't a problem, if the calibration software gives it the exact same greenish tint every time, and can do the same for any monitor you use.  It just means your room is more magenta than x-rite's labs (I'm kidding, but to make a point; it's consistency that matters).

Comment: @JasonConrad hmm ok thanks for the article